# SystemStackError upon creating new rails app, can't update rubygems, gives argumenterror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been working on this all night.  I created a new rails app and tried to install some gems and got "bundler 2 only works with rubygems 2.5". I tried to update --system but got back argument error. I then tried to create another app (I'm not sure if this happened the first time I was busy texting) and it gave "gemfile fileutils" a lot until it said

```
'''Traceback (most recent call last):
    8888: from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/rails:26:in `<main>'
    8887: from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/rails:26:in `load'
    8886: from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
    8885: from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    8884: from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    8883: from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    8882: from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    8881: from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
     ... 8876 levels...
       4: from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/shell.rb:60:in `say_status'
       3: from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb:110:in `say_status'
       2: from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb:390:in `quiet?'
       1: from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/core_ext/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb:20:in `[]'
```

/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/core_ext/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb:74:in `convert_key': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)'''

I've tried everything a beginner could from trying to install rubygems every way I could, reinstalled rails, made sure everything was up to date but no luck. I've been working at this for just under 2.5 hours googling and what not so I'm sure there are smaller things I forgot about that I've tried.

Comment: It seems the error is coming from `thor`, can you see if theres a line in the gemfile and comment it out?

Comment: Okay.. sorry for the delay. I had posted this before going to sleep as I have work early in the morning. Just got home and read your comment.. found nothing in the gemfile for thor however I went and tried (litterally) exactly what I was doing yesterday and everything is working fine. I have no idea what happened or even if it will work the next time I boot everything up but as of now I have no issues lol.. Thanks for the response! @maxpleaner